# How do you safely identify whether an mp4 is an audio only or video file

Tags: video, audio, mp4

Given a set of mp4 files I want to identify only the Audio files not the Video files. Previously I did this by ensuring there was only one trak atom, and that track atom contained a `trak.mdia.minf.smhd` atom but since found this was excluding some valid audio files.

So now I check each trak atom found in the file and only reject if we find a `trak.mdia.minf.vmhd` atom in any of the atoms OR we don't find at least one `trak.mdia.minf.smhd` atom. But I'm sure this isn't watertight as there must be video formats that don't use a `vmhd` atom.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look for the track type in `trak->mdia->hdlr->handlerType` where the `handlerType` is `soun` for audio or `vide` for video.

Comment: Thanks sounds a bit simpler than what I ended up doing was for each moov.trak.mdia.minf atom if it contained a vmhd atom means video. I guess whichever way you do it you need to check every trak atom, and whilst it is ok to have more than one trak atom, if you find any containing vmhd atom or handler type of vide then reject.